# Show geom_vline in legend as horizontal lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am putting together plots which have various `geom_vline`'s with different line types. The problem is that they are not easily distinguished in the legend, especially as the number of line types increases. I'm wondering if there is a way to show these as horizontal lines in the legend, as the only lines in the graph are vertical.

Example:

```
plot_test <- ggplot() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1, linetype="Line 1"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, linetype="Line 2"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3, linetype="Line 3"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 4, linetype="Line 4"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 5, linetype="Line 5"), linewidth=1) +
  scale_linetype_manual("",values=c("Line 1"=1, "Line 2"=2, "Line 3" = 3, "Line 4"=4, "Line 5"=5))+
  theme_bw()

plot_test
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`key_glyph`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html) argument with `path` to rotate the lines horizontally:

```r
library(ggplot2)
plot_test <- ggplot() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1, linetype="Line 1"), linewidth=1, key_glyph = "path") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, linetype="Line 2"), linewidth=1, key_glyph = "path") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3, linetype="Line 3"), linewidth=1, key_glyph = "path") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 4, linetype="Line 4"), linewidth=1, key_glyph = "path") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 5, linetype="Line 5"), linewidth=1, key_glyph = "path") +
  scale_linetype_manual("",values=c("Line 1"=1, "Line 2"=2, "Line 3" = 3, "Line 4"=4, "Line 5"=5))+
  theme_bw()

plot_test
```

[image]

---

Alternative is using one `geom_vline` to just use the `key_glyph` once. Also please check @AllanCameron's answer which of course works perfect:

```r
library(ggplot2)
plot_test <- ggplot() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                 linetype=c("Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3", "Line 4", "Line 5")), 
             linewidth=1, key_glyph = "path") +
  scale_linetype_manual("",values=c("Line 1"=1, "Line 2"=2, "Line 3" = 3, "Line 4"=4, "Line 5"=5))+
  theme_bw() 

plot_test
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice answer. Any idea why something like `guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes = list(key_glyph="path")))` wouldn't work to change them all rather that editing each layer?

Comment: @MrFlick I think it's simply because `key_glyph` isn't an aesthetic. It's a data member of the `geom`. Drawing the scale guides sometimes involves combining the draw keys of several geoms in combination.

Comment: @MrFlick though strangely enough, you can write another `draw_key` function directly to the `draw_key` member of `GeomVline`. Doing so seems to change the namespace of the object.

Comment: @MrFlick, I was thinking the same. Luckily Allan has of course found a perfect way. Alternatively, we can use one geom.

Comment: @AllanCameron. You're right. It's not an aes. I got the parenthesis mixed up in my head. Makes sense. But this feels like something you should be able to change via `guides` so maybe it's worth filing as an issue with ggplot

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Don't know how I missed the `key_glyph` argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have your plot object and just want to change the draw key for you can do it directly by changing the geom.

Suppose we start with your plot:

```r
plot_test
```

[image]

We can simply do

```r
GeomVline$draw_key <- draw_key_path

plot_test
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Tough call which to accept, so I went on first answer. +1 for your answer for minimal code though!